# MS Access Write Conflict when porting backend from MS SQL to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have been tasked with moving an application from an Access front-end with MS SQL back-end, to a MYSQL back-end. The application is like 20 years old and has been added to, changed, and made a mess repeatedly over the past 20 years so anything is possible.

I have a form "Tract View" which is mostly linked to three tables: Tracts, Customers, and Land Company. There are other tabs which include subforms linked to other tables such as Payments, Taxes, Sales People, Docs, Association, etc. All of these subforms are of course linked to the TractID displayed on the main Tract View form.

The problem is, if I open the Tract View and then close it when the application is connected to the MYSQL back-end I get a "Write Conflict" and "This record has been changed by another user since you started editing it." with options to Copy to Clipboard or Drop Changes (Save Record is greyed out). The error occurs right at the DoCmd.Close command in the code of the Quit button, although there is a lot more code that executes with the Form_Close and Form_Unload subs.

I have added a Timestamp(2) to all the tables involved (I think) with the default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2). Since I am running MYSQL at this point I have no BIT columns, they have all been converted to TINYINTs.

When the application is connected to the original MS SQL server I do not have this issue.

Anyone have any directions to go? Things to check on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft-access.html) help? Is "return matching rows instead of affected" activated?

Comment: LOL, yes, that worked perfectly! I also very much appreciate the link to the document, will be keeping that very handy for this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"return matching rows instead of affected"* needs to be activated.